# Parse JSON using JQuery

Tags: json

I am receiving JSON string response from my WCF service. I wanna parse this JSON to respective objects. So i have done like below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://URL/Service.svc/LoginValidation?',
    success: function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (response != "") {
        var JSON=response.replace(/^"|"$/g, '\''); // replace Start and End double Quotes with single quotes. becze JSON string should be start and end with single quotes while parsing this.
        var obj = JSON.parse(JSON); // Here is my problem. While accessing JSON variable here that automatically showing double quotes. so that here showing syntax error.
            UserID = obj.UserID;
            ClientID = obj.ClientID;
            DomainName = obj.DomainName;
            AuthenticationKey = obj.AuthenticationKey;
        }
        else {
            alert("Invalid UserName or Password.");
        }
    }
});
```

How to parse this JSON data. can we do this using JQuery.

Comment: Set the `$.ajax` call's dataType to `json`, or just use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ method since you're not using the error callback anyways.

Comment: jquery automatically does this if you specify the returned data type through `dataType : "json"` attribute in your ajax request.

Comment: u people great. working fine.. Thanks a lot all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax()` call options and jQuery will parse it and provide the decoded object to your `success` handler.

Comment: ur great Lanzz.. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

use getJSON function as

```
      $.getJSON('http://URL/Service.svc/LoginValidation?',function(data)
       {
        var JSON=data.replace(/^"|"$/g, '\''); 
        UserID = JSON.UserID;
        ClientID = JSON.ClientID;
        DomainName = JSON.DomainName;
        AuthenticationKey = JSON.AuthenticationKey;
           // do remaining stuffs
       })  
    });
```